# Regex to replace 'li' with 'option' without losing class and id attributes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am looking for a solution using preg_replace or similar method to change:

```
<li id="id1" class="authorlist" />
<li id="id2" class="authorlist" />
<li id="id3" class="authorlist" />
```

to

```
<option id="id1" class="authorlist" />
<option id="id2" class="authorlist" />
<option id="id3" class="authorlist" />
```

I think I have the pattern correct, but not sure how to do the replacement part...

Here is the (wordpress) php code:

```
$string = wp_list_authors( $args ); //returns list as noted above
$pattern = '<li ([^>]*)';
$replacement = '?????';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Suggestions, please?

Comment: Uh oh, too many helpful editors...

Comment: You should click `edit`, copy the question's source, delete the question, and re-ask it.

Comment: I wonder if a 1 minute delay between edits would be helpful?

Comment: http://us.php.net/str_replace is going to be better than a regex in this case.

Answer (score 6):

I think a simple string replacement would be best

```
str_replace('<li', '<option', $string)
```

Same for ending tags

```
str_replace('</li', '</option', $string)
```

Comment: *Sigh* Community wiki, why must you deny me my sweet, sweet reputation points?

Comment: Clearly, the whole world is against you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
echo str_replace('</li', '</option', (str_replace('<li', '<option', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a delimiter in the pattern. For example:

```
$pattern = '@<li @';
$replacement = '<option ';
```